# table.setItem() is called inappropriately

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a table with all editable cells. When one of these is changed `cellChange()` starts updating the DB.

The problem is that when you press "Select", even without making any changes, it triggers the error message `"Value must be CAPITAL"`.

```
class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.calendar(self)

    def calendar(self, MainWindow):
        self.allyears = ['2021', '2022', '2023', '2024']
        self.number = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
        self.alldata = [['name1', 'value10', 'value11', 'value12', 'value13' ],
                         ['name2', 'value20', 'value21', 'value22', 'value23'],
                         ['name3', 'value30', 'value31', 'value32', 'value33'],
                         ['name4', 'value40', 'value41', 'value42', 'value43']]
        self.this_month = strftime("%-m")
        self.this_year = strftime("%Y")
        self.this_month = '2'
        global this_month, this_year
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 100, 500, 300))
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Calendari Mensili")
        global daysinmonth
        this_year = strftime("%Y")
        this_month = strftime("%-m")
        self.table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 300, 200))
        self.table.setColumnCount(7)
        self.table.setRowCount(1)
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(True)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(5)
        self.ySel = QtWidgets.QComboBox(MainWindow)
        self.ySel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 10, 80, 20))
        self.ySel.addItems(self.allyears)
        self.ySel.setCurrentText(self.this_year)
        self.mSel = QtWidgets.QComboBox(MainWindow)
        self.mSel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 10, 100, 20))
        self.mSel.addItems(self.number)
        self.mSel.setCurrentText(self.number[int(self.this_month) - 1])
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
        self.btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 40, 50, 15))
        self.btn.setText("Select")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.cal_Select)
        i = 0
        while i <= 3:
            self.table.insertRow(i +1)
            zz = 0
            while zz <= 4:
                item = self.alldata[i][zz]
                cell =  QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.table.setItem(i, zz, cell)
                zz +=1
            i += 1
        MainWindow.show()
        self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.cellChange)


    def cellChange(self, item):
        row = item.row()
        col = item.column()
        print(str(row) + '---' + str(col))
        val = self.table.item(row, col).text()
        if val == ' ': print("Cell cant contain a space"); return
        if val.islower() == True: print("Value must be CAPITAL"); return

    def cal_Select(self):
        i = 3
        while i >= 0:
            zz = 0
            while zz <= 1:
                item = self.alldata[i][zz]
                cell = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.table.setItem(i, zz, cell)
                zz += 1
            i -= 1

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    thisapp = App()
    thisapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is your question why `val.islower()` is true when you make no changes?

Comment: Or is your question why `self.table.setItem` is called?

Comment: Or is your question why `setItem` triggers `itemChanged`?

Comment: My question is that `self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.cellChange)` should not be callaed when I press `Select`

Comment: You could delete the line `self.table.setItem(i, zz. cell)`.

Comment: Or you could delete the line `self.btn.clicked.connect(self.cal_Select)`.

Comment: Use `self.table.itemChanged.disconnect(self.cellChange)` before the beginning of the loop and reconnect it again at the end. Also, use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: @musicamente. Thanbk you. It works